# Get Forge App access token by manual triggering in Power Automate

Tags: autodesk-forge, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I am trying to get my forge app access token using a manual trigger in Power Automate.  I keep receiving an error saying The client credentials are invalid.
I use " https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token " endpoint for this, and this is my body in the HTTP post

client_id=OJP5THOTP8tGNOdEzc3aZfSM********&client_secret=yWINmvxvvX13****&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=data:read%20data:write

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Po5Vj.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYCfN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use OAuth2 V2, your request body of https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token is not correct. The body you specified is still the old V1.

Check the link https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-2-legged-token/ for the usage,

Here is one example:

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v2/token' \
   -X 'POST' \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
   -H 'Accept: application/json' \
   -H 'Authorization: Basic <BASE64_ENCODED_STRING_FROM_STEP_1>' \
   -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' \
   -d 'scope=data:read'
```